# Get elements inside #document using PUPPEETER

Tags: html, node.js, puppeteer

I'm new here, so you can help me!?

I need get some elements inside a virtual reference ***#document*** html, using puppetter, but When I try I receive a message it element doesn't exist.

Follow examples:

HTML

```
<div class="row" id="mainDiv">
    <iframe id="mainFrame" src="...">        
           #document
                <html>
                    <head></head>
                    <body>
                        <div id="firstDIV">
                            <div id="secondDIV">
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" id="inputMain" name="principalInput">
                        </div>
                    </body>
                </html>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

I need to get value from input in that example. But puppeeteer doesn't access anything inside **#document**

I'm using **nodeJS**

Comment: Try using `.contentFrame()` on the iFrame element from Puppeteer in order to get the inner document. It's asynchronous so you will have to `await` it.

If that doesn't work, you may want to provide more details as to your Puppeteer code itself - that's important to helping others provide relevant solutions!

Comment: Hey dude! Follow the code: `` const iframeElement = await page.$('#mainFrame') const frame = await iframeElement.contentFrame() console.log('started') const value = await frame.$eval('#inputMain', input => input.value) console.log('finished') await page.evaluate((val) => { document.getElementById('inputMain').value = "READY" }, value) `` In that eg, console log just for test, because 'finished' doesn't show. I guess, 'await' stop the code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can try something like this:

```js
const iframeElement = await page.$('#mainFrame');
const frame = await iframeElement.contentFrame();
const value = await frame.$eval('#inputMain', input => input.value);
```

Comment: Hey dude! Thanks for your answer!

I did exacly you said, but didn't works. Follow code:

``
  const iframeElement = await page.$('#mainFrame')
  const frame = await iframeElement.contentFrame()
  console.log('started')
  const value = await frame.$eval('#inputMain', input => input.value)
  console.log('finished')

  await page.evaluate((val) => {
    document.getElementById('inputMain').value = "READY"
  }, value)
``
In that eg, console log just for test, because 'finished' doesn't show. I guess, 'await' stop the code.

Comment: So, no error messages in the console, the code just hangs?

Comment: Exactly! no errors. I try to see wat is inside input, but function doesn't execute. Like this

const value = await frame.$eval('#inputMain', input => console.log(input)) -> its doesn't run.

Comment: Do you check the browser console? `const value = await frame.$eval('#inputMain', input => console.log(input))` would output to browser console, not the Node.js (system) console.

Comment: Yes. Browser console is clear like water.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot make a guess what may be the cause(