# Puppeteer doesn't find button, doesn't recognize loaded website

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

First time using Puppeteer and trying to simply click this button

[image: button to be pressed]

after clicking the deny cookies button. That's my code:

```
await page.goto('https://myurl.com');
await page.click('a.cc-btn.cc-deny');
// await page.waitForNavigation();

await page.waitForSelector("#detailview_btn_order", {visible: true});
await page.click("#detailview_btn_order");
```

Clicking the deny cookies button works like a charm. However, it seems the second button can't be identified by Puppeteer. If I don't use `waitForSelector` it just says it can't find it. If I use it, I get a timeout after 30 seconds even though the website finishes loading after 5 seconds. If I uncomment `waitForNavigation` (regardless of what options I use) I get a timeout there, even thoug the site loads within seconds. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Could you show the website?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```js
await page.goto('https://myurl.com');

await Promise.all([
  page.click('a.cc-btn.cc-deny'),
  page.waitForNavigation(),
]);

const iframeElement = await page.waitForSelector("#my-iframe");
const frame = await iframeElement.contentFrame();

await frame.waitForSelector("#detailview_btn_order", {visible: true});
await frame.click("#detailview_btn_order");
```

Sometimes there is [a race condition between a click and navigation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately still the same result :(
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 
ms exceeded

Comment: @gizarmaluke Well, it is worth providing the site URL then)

Comment: The site is not available at the moment. I can provide something I found out, though. When using the browser's console and executing `document.querySelector("#detailview_btn_order")`, the result is `null`. But as soon as I right-click the button and inspect it, `document.querySelector("#detailview_btn_order")` returns the element.

Comment: @gizarmaluke Then maybe the button is inside an iframe. You need something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66342967/get-elements-inside-document-using-puppeeter/66360319#66360319

Comment: Thanks so much for your patience and answers! So do I understand correctly: I first assign the iFrame element to `iframeElement`, then resolve its contents and assign them to `frame`, then look for the button inside `frame` and specify what I want to do with it in the callback function?

  `await Promise.all([
    page.waitForSelector("#my-iframe"),
    page.click('a.cc-btn.cc-deny'),
  ]);

const iframeElement = await page.$('#iframe-name');
const frame = await iframeElement.contentFrame();
await frame.$eval('#detailview_btn_order', async(button) => {await page.click(button)});`

Comment: @gizarmaluke I've updated the answer with a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still stuck at the very first step tough :( : `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded`. If I replace `waitForNavigation` with `waitForTimeout(10000)`, I get `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'waitForSelector' of null`.

Comment: @gizarmaluke Sorry( I cannot think of another solution.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for the effort, though!